# dotnetcore asp understand Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to dotnetcore so please be patient...

this ASP controller method works if I give back a list of Strings.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Contract> Get()
    {
        return getContracts();
    }
```

meanwhile every thing is public...it's just later where I see the error

If I return a list of very simple objects I get the warning

Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'type' is less accessible than method 'method'

the documentation for that error only shows an example for that. But how to fix it ?

Also thanks for any Link/Hint to understand the issue/rules here !

Comment: You need to make the class Contract public. E.g. `public class Contract`.

Comment: thought so too and changed the question for it... it's all public !  just later where I see the error and still I don't understand why a List of String has a different publicity than my own object List

Comment: damm you are right....post your answer and I vote for it ! just missed on public in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is defined as:

```cs
class Contract
{
}
```

Then you will get the error because a class is internal by default.
A public method on a public class can't return internal types.

So we make the class public:

```cs
public class Contract
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. didn't check the class so omitted the public there